# IE7 Javascript and using string as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, internet-explorer

Weird behavior and I'm just posting this question to see if anyone knows the reason for this or whether my code is just plain wrong:

```
string text = "~"; //yip, let's take some weird character
alert(text[0]);
//all major browsers output "~"
//IE6 & 7: undefined
alert(text.charAt(0));
//works in all browsers
```

Now my question is: Is using a text as an array not supported in IE7, is the code wrong in general and is it OK to use `.charAt(i)` instead of `string[i]`?

PS: There is [some guy who answered his own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526019/simple-javascript-string-problem-in-ie6-and-ie7) regarding exactly this. My question remains: Where is this documented? Is this a regular IE "bug"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accessing string array-like is not standard in ECMAScript 3:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#section_5

> Array-like character access (the second way above) is not part of
>   ECMAScript 3. It is a JavaScript and ECMAScript 5 feature.

What you do is split the string:

```
var textChars = text.split('');
alert(textChars[0]);
```

Comment: Perfect! So IE did it correctly, all other browsers are just nice to me using strings as arrays.